# Some Windows AD user property cannot be changed by AD user himself, what controls it?

Tags: active-directory

I'm curious with a question I find. An Windows Active Directory user can change his own telephone number, street address etc, but can NOT change his own email-address registered on the AD.

Using Python+pywin32 I can also verify this behavior. When trying to change own EmailAddress, I got error **General access denied error** .

[image]

I'd like to know where in the AD this allow/deny behavior is defined. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends completely on the access control list applied to your user objects, you should take a look at what these are set to for your domain.

It appears that you have the defaults set at the moment - a user has default write access to their "Personal Information" property set (which includes `telephoneNumber`, see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728117%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)), but they do not have access to write the `mail` attribute.

It's probably not writable by default because Exchange sets and uses it - consider carefully what it's being used for before setting it to writable by users.

Comment: Where can I view the ACL for a specific user object? Can ADExplorer show or modify that information? Could supply in your answer  some links that refers to such tools(better with screen shots)?

Comment: @JimmChen You can view the ACL in the Users and Computers snap-in (`dsa.msc`); set "Advanced Features" in the View menu then the Security tab will show up when viewing objects.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it. I even need to click the **Advanced** button in the security tab to view all that hundreds of permissions for an user object.